Missing Resources for Pyflink Job
I am running a pyflink job in a docker container. I am using flink 1.18. When I am running a job which is present in the example directory ,the job is getting submitted. When I check the logs, I see the following line:-
Missing resources: Job f0de3394ec5a6d78bb0c6801b145e79e ResourceRequirement{resourceProfile=ResourceProfile{UNKNOWN}, numberOfRequiredSlots=1}
This is my docker config file:-
services:
  jobmanager:
    image: pyflink:latest
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    command: jobmanager
    environment:
      FLINK_PROPERTIES: |
        jobmanager.rpc.address: jobmanager

  taskmanager:
    image: pyflink:latest
    depends_on:
      - jobmanager
    command: taskmanager
    environment:
      FLINK_PROPERTIES: |
        jobmanager.rpc.address: jobmanager
        taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: 4
    deploy:
      replicas: 2


I want to solve this issue and I am confused as to why this issue persists
